# Проверка принадлежности числа отрезку (центр ± радиус)

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как сделать проверку на принадлежность числа `x` отрезку

```
[middle - radius, middle + radius]
```

Например, если

```
middle = 30
radius = 10
```

то проверку должны проходить числа 20, 23, 25, 37, 31 и т.д.

Comment: Какие пути решения вы уже опробовали?

Answer (score 6):

Использовать оператор нестрого сравнения `<=` и логического И `&&`:

```
// число, которое является серединой отрезка
int middle = 30;
// число, которое проверяем на принадлежность отрезку [middle - 10, middle + 10]
int x = ...
// булевая переменная, означающая, лежит ли x внутри отрезка
bool accept = middle - 10 <= x && x <= middle + 10;
```

Условие можно написать по-другому, используя функцию [`abs`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs), которая возвращает модуль числа:

```
bool accept = abs(x - middle) <= 10;
```

---

Если вы работаете с числами, близкими к `INT_MIN` или `INT_MAX` (то есть возможно переполнение при вычитании), то можно переписать код так:

```
int middle = 30;
int radius = 10;
int x = ...

assert(radius >= 0);
int minNumber = min(x, middle);
int maxNumber = max(x, middle);
bool accept = minNumber > 0
    ? minNumber >= maxNumber - radius
    : minNumber + radius >= maxNumber;
```

Вроде работает без переполнения с любыми `x`, `middle` и любым положительным `radius`

Comment: или abs(x - middle) <= 10

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, да, спасибо)

Comment: Не совсем корректно был задан вопрос, у меня есть код для получения координат курсора, и вот как мне туда пристроить эту проверку чтобы пользователь мог подвинуть мышь в пределах ну допустим 200 пикселей? Я вот сейчас сижу никак не понимаю.

Comment: @Aleksei.C ну, проверьте две координаты или посчитайте декартово расстояние между двумя точками.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, если у вас есть только код получения координат курсора, то, к сожалению, реализовать запрет на передвижение курсора вне определённой области не получится. Если же у вас также есть код **установки** координат курсора, то можно каждую секунду получать координаты курсора и если они не лежат в нужной области, то перемещать курсор в последнюю корректную позицию.

Comment: упомяните, что будет в районе `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX`

Comment: @jfs, написал версию без переполнения. Правда, вряд ли она кому-то пригодится.

Answer (score 2):

> Не совсем корректно был задан вопрос, у меня есть код для получения
>   координат курсора, и вот как мне туда пристроить эту проверку чтобы
>   пользователь мог подвинуть мышь в пределах ну допустим 200 пикселей? Я
>   вот сейчас сижу никак не понимаю.

Следующий код ограничивает область передвижения курсора мыши в прямоугольнике 200 пикселей от текущей позиции мыши:

```
// получаем текущую позицию курсора мыши 
POINT pos_mouse;
GetCursorPos(&pos_mouse);

// ограничиваем область передвижения
RECT rect;
rect.left = pos_mouse.x;
rect.top = pos_mouse.y;
rect.bottom = pos_mouse.y + 200;
rect.right = pos_mouse.x + 200;
ClipCursor(&rect);
```